# How to make onclick to another activty from android widget

Tags: android, widget

i want make onclick from my android stack widget with sent any paramether to another activity.

This My RemoteViewsFactory code :

```
package com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.widgets;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
import com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.Config;
import com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.R;
import com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.activity.MovieActivity;
import com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.model.Movie;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import static com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.utils.MoviesContract.MoviesColumns.CONTENT_URI;

public class StackRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    private Context mContext;
    int mAppWidgetId;
    private Cursor cursor;
    Movie movie;

    public StackRemoteViewsFactory(Context applicationContext, Intent intent) {
        mContext = applicationContext;
        mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.close();
        }
        final long token = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
        cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(token);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.movies_widget_item);
        if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            movie =new Movie(cursor);
            Bitmap bmp;
            try {
                bmp = Glide.with(mContext)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load(Config.IMAGE_MEDIUM_BASE_URL + movie.getPosterPath())
                        .into(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                        .get();
                rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.poster, bmp);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                Log.d("Widget Load Error", "error");
            }
        }
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_title, movie.getTitle());
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putInt(Config.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
            Intent fillInIntent = new Intent(mContext, MovieActivity.class);
            fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
            fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.MOVIE_ID, movie.getId());
            fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.TITLE, movie.getTitle());
            fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.POSTER, movie.getPosterPath());
            fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.RELEASE_DATE, movie.getReleaseDate());
            fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.RATING, String.valueOf(movie.getRating()));
        rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.poster, fillInIntent);
        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is my Widget Provider code :

```
package com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.widgets;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.R;

import static com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.Config.EXTRA_ITEM;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class MoviesWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String TOAST_ACTION = "com.erlanggakmoekasan.imovie.TOAST_ACTION";

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.movies_widget);
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.stack_view, intent);

        Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, MoviesWidget.class);

        toastIntent.setAction(TOAST_ACTION);
        toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, toastPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(TOAST_ACTION)) {
                int viewIndex = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, 0);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Touched view " + viewIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

how to implement the onclick method in widget android with sent all paramether ... to another activity on RemoteViewsFactory i'm using `setOnClickFillInIntent` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This In OnReceive

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Opening...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Intent mailClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mailClient.putExtra("TITLE","Hindi");
mailClient.setClassName("com.package.name", "com.package.name.ToActivity");


mailClient.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

context.startActivity(mailClient);
```

Comment: how to sent this item fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.MOVIE_ID, movie.getId());
            fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.TITLE, movie.getTitle());
            fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.POSTER, movie.getPosterPath());
            fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.RELEASE_DATE, movie.getReleaseDate());
            fillInIntent.putExtra(MovieActivity.RATING, String.valueOf(movie.getRating())); from content provider data???

Comment: Try Something Like This  in widget activity Intent intent = getIntent();
       // String easyPuzzle = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)){

            String disp = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            Toast.makeText(this, disp
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }